# Running SSIS jobs from SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I'm looking for a nice user-friendly interface for starting SSIS jobs:

- Users shouldn't need SSMS or other software installed on their desktop
- Users can provide parameter values that are passed through to SSIS

SSRS seems like a possible choice - you can run reports from the web browser, and there's a good interface for providing parameter values.

But how can I kick off a SSIS job from a SSRS report, and pass through the parameter values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS isn't interactive in that way. You can filter and sort, but not call out to other processes without some custom DLL.

I'd consider a simple web app (which is what SSRS is of course) with the code behind calling SSIS via .net

Comment: In the end I created a SSRS report and used an XSLT file to transform the report XML output into the required data file format. This allows users to use the SSRS web UI and parameters to configure the report, get a preview, and then when they are happy export it as a file.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use Reporting Services for this task. It is designed to display and show your data, not to manage it.

One way to create a user-friendly interface for SSIS is with an ASP.net website.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SSIS_DOTNET.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can enable SSRS reports to trigger and show data from SSIS packages - see [details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345250%28SQL.100%29.aspx) - but note the dire warnings about lack of support and this feature not being production-ready.

Another way ot approach this is to use SSRS to trigger SSIS indirectly - I've done similar things in the past using SSRS to trigger SQL Agent jobs (which can in turn trigger SSIS packages) but that was for packages which didn't require run-time parameters.